# Google Analytic UA-xxx question

Tags: google-analytics

There is many way to create a new account in Google Analytic
create a new UA-xxx number
or make a new one under an existing UA-xxx-y (y) y is increment number 1,2,3,4....and so on

two questions : I have come close to the 50 limit, so maybe doing new account under a already created is a way to trick the system to have more than 50.

But second question. is there a difference or a drawback to make two completely different site under the same UA-xxx number with just the last digit different... eh, in fact it's a new number.. no ?

You Google Analytic pro out there please help me, the help forum is unanswered or completely useless
Thanks in advance

I what to know...do i generate a new UA-1234-1 for a new site or using a already generate UA-1234 with anothe digit a the ens is fine UA-1234-6

Comment: these 2 sites completely different , how do you want to merge the analytics data for both !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only connection between UA-123-1 and UA-123-2 is that they're organized under the same menu, and so permissions are managed in the same way.

If two sites have nothing to do with each other, and you run up against a limit for UA-123-50 (if that is the limit), there's no drawback in beginning to move your new sites to UA-124-1.

As a general organizational rule, the grouping of UA-123 is just organizational, not technological, since GA sends the data only to the full account specified (UA-123-4). So, sites tagged with UA-123-4 will never share data with sites tagged UA-123-1. As a matter of course, I try to keep related sites in the same UA account, and separate them with -1, -2, etc.

One other important fact is that if you ever want to give someone Admin access to a particular part of your account, you can't. That is, to grant someone Admin access, they are given full access to everything under UA-123.

The only level at which collisions of data can occur is at UA-123-1. If you put UA-123-1 on two separate sites (without filtering), both of the sites' data will appear in that account.

So, there's no harm in creating many different accounts on the same login; I myself have dozens.

Comment: @yahelc, if I have native mobile app, does I need to set UA-1234-1 or UA-1234-3 or UA-1234-5 or etc? which last digit is recommended?

Comment: @gaussblurinc It's not a matter of recommendation. It's whichever is assigned to the profile you're using. They're just auto-incrementing for each profile on an account, so the first on the account will be -1, and is generally the one you see the most. After that, -2, -3, etc.